# Issue regarding string representation of SPUser object in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, migration, spuser

I am facing an issue in SharePoint 2013 regarding string representation of `SPUser` object.

I am migrating my SharePoint site from SharePoint 2010 platform to SharePoint 2013 platform. I have a code, which is processing `SPUser.ToString()` string.

In SP 2010, I was getting string from `SPUser` as follows:

```
<<User ID>>;#<<Display Name>>
```

for example:

```
12;#testUser
```

In SP 2013, I am SPUser string for the same user is as follows:

```
12;#testUser,#i:05.t|adfs|testUser@dev.local,#testUser@dev.local,#,#testUser,#,#,#
```

It is showing id, display name, claim string, email address etc.

I was able to handle changes in above string representation by altering my code. I have searched on web to find details regarding above string representation. I got nothing.

My questions are:

1. Is this change in string representation of `SPUser` object part of SP2013?
2. What are all `#` separated strings represent?